# Git conflict when pulling from repo forked from me, even though last thing I did was pull from it

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull, git-fork

## Context

Long time ago I created https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android ("**repo1**").

Someone forked it into https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android ("**repo2**") which is now the place where we all collaborate.

## What I want to do

I would like to update **repo1** to have the latest source code from **repo2** (so that I can create feature branches and send pull requests).

## What I tried

In my local clone of **repo1**, I ran `git pull <repo2> master` but I get a huge conflict.

I find this very surprising because the [last thing I did](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/commits/master) was the exact same command.  How can there be a conflict even though I have not modified repo1 since I last pulled from **repo2**? *(I just deleted my local repo and re-cloned from **repo1** so you can be sure it is not a problem with my local repo)*

I think I can't use `rebase` since **repo2** has originally been forked from my repo **repo1**.

Comment: I haven't taken a close look at your commit logs yet, but it sounds like someone might have rewrote existing commits in the forked repo, like through a rebase, cherry-pick, amendment, etc. That's the first thing I would check. I'll dig around right now, in fact...

Comment: The 2nd repo isn't actually directly forked from your repo, it's forked from [this one](https://github.com/flerda/Anki-Android), which is forked from yours. So there's 3 repos involved.

Comment: Another possibility is line-ending differences (Windows vs OS X). I'm still checking...

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows? OS X? What about your collaborators? Is anyone using `core.autocrlf` set to `true` for their git config?

Comment: Do you really need/care about what's on repo1? If not, just force-push repo2's HEAD to it, and never mind.

Comment: "How can there be a conflict even though I have not modified repo1 since I last pulled from repo2?" So that statement isn't entirely correct. [You did a merge commit in your local `master` branch](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/commit/5d4ad0f3ce4e8742698597e0d59ea67f8f245af0), it wasn't a fast-forward merge...so since your local `master` contains commits that repo2 doesn't have, it's actually not surprising that you get another merge commit with conflicts. Still though, something strange is going on...I'm having trouble finding `tag: v2.0.1` in repo2's `master` history...

Comment: @NicolasRaoul ok, well if you're happy with overwriting your repo's contents with repo2's contents with a force-push, then I'm not going to bother to keep digging through what's wrong with repo1 in the first place. But I did find something strange. Repo1's `master` branch contains this commit that's tagged as `v2.0.1`: `eac0483a9bf8816af7dbbe38935e48960f7911be`. That commit and tag also show up in Repo2, but none of Repo2's branches contain them. I have a suspicion that someone went and pushed rewritten commits to Repo2, or otherwise cut out that line of development entirely.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia: Sorry I did not understand fully the consequences of force-push (never used it). There are still a hundred people who have forked from various points of my repo, so doing something that violent might not be a good idea apparently.

Comment: @Cupcake: Isn't it this commit? https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/commit/eac0483a9

Comment: @Cupcake: I use Linux like most of my collaborators, but at least a few use Windows. On the number, some might be using `core.autocrlf` indeed, difficult to check with everyone unfortunately. I did not rewrite any commit (except for commit message) but some might have.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes, that's the commit, ***but what branch contains it?*** When I did `git commit -a --contains eac0483a9bf8816af7dbbe38935e48960f7911be` with a clone of Repo2, none of the branches showed up as containing that commit. Just because the commit exists in the repo, it doesn't mean that any branches actually have it. It's just got the `v2.0.1` tag attached to it, that's it.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I just checked all of the tags in Repo2 as well, only `v2.0.1` contains commit `eac0483a9bf8816af7dbbe38935e48960f7911be`, none of the newer tags contain it. I suspect that someone must have done a pretty significant rewrite of a bunch of commits that were already pushed publicly.

Comment: @Cupcake: Sorry I had misundertood! It might not be on any branch indeed... Is there any way I could get over this, and get the most recent code, on which I could start contributing normally? Thanks for the investigation!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul talk to your team members and find out if anyone has a copy of the current commits in your personal fork. If not, then you can consider doing a force-push to update your fork with the contents of the team fork. Otherwise, another option is to just fork the team fork again, i.e. make yourself a new personal fork.

Comment: However, you shouldn't have been forced into this position in the first place. The fact that none of the new work in the team fork contains tag `v2.0.1` indicates that either someone did a significant rewrite of public commits and didn't tell anyone, or they did tell people, and you just didn't find out about it until now.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is simply to replace the current `repo1` `master` branch by the one from `repo2`.

```
 cd repo1
 git add remote repo2 /url/repo2
 git fetch repo2
 git checkout master
 git reset --hard repo2/master
 git push -f
```

If you are the only one working on `repo1`, forcing a new history on it won't impact anyone else.
Even it there were people having clone repo1, the collaboration in at repo2 now, so again it doesn't matter.

But if you want to be extra careful, you can:

- create a new branch based on `repo2/master`
- push that new branch on `repo1`
- make your pull request (to `repo2`) from branches done from that new branch on `repo1`

In that last case, no forced push, no harm.

Answer (score 1):

[@VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22979923/456814) is excellent, I hadn't even considered the option of just adding and pushing another branch based off of Repo2's master. I'd like to add additional info about why this is even happening though.

So after lots of digging around, I found the point of divergence between Repo1 and Repo2. The current oldest common ancestor between the master branch of both repos is exactly at tag `v2.0`:

```
git log -1 4e4bafe
commit 4e4bafed59520908e4f1e7f0b3cb71f96f59a236
Author: nobnago <ksdfhskdjfwdewf@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 3 11:36:00 2013 +0100

    bump version 2.0
```

After that point, the two branches appear to not have any common history anymore. I mentioned in my comments to the question that I suspected that someone rewrote publicly pushed commits afterwards, because Repo2 contains tag `v2.0.1`, but the commit that the tag references isn't contained in any of the branches in Repo2, nor in any of other tags (including the newest ones).

However, when looking at the logs for the master branches, I don't see any clear evidence of rewritten commits (authored dates that wildly differ from commited dates, and where the author and committer are different people):

```
# Repo2. "datelog" is an alias that displays author/author-date
# on the left, and committer/commit-date on the right.
git datelog -3 9f38b64
*   9f38b64 Flavio Lerda Flavio Lerda Thu Jan 3 15:11:35 2013 -0800 Thu Jan 3 23:14:33 2013 +0000 Merge pull request #1 from agrueneberg/searchbox
|\
| * b397e36 Alexander Grüneberg Alexander Grüneberg Sat Nov 17 21:16:03 2012 -0600 Thu Jan 3 16:27:47 2013 -0600 Search on Enter key.
* | 4e4bafe nobnago nobnago Thu Jan 3 11:36:00 2013 +0100 Thu Jan 3 11:36:00 2013 +0100 bump version 2.0

# Repo1
git datelog -2 badbf87
* badbf87 nobnago nobnago Thu Jan 3 12:55:42 2013 +0100 Thu Jan 3 12:55:42 2013 +0100 uncomment logs
* 4e4bafe nobnago nobnago Thu Jan 3 11:36:00 2013 +0100 Thu Jan 3 11:36:00 2013 +0100 bump version 2.0
```

What I do see in Repo1's logs, however, is that you didn't synchronize your fork with Repo2 until about 4.5 months later!:

```
git datelog -1 nicolas/master
*   5d4ad0f Nicolas Raoul Nicolas Raoul Wed Apr 17 14:40:24 2013 +0900 Wed Apr 17 14:40:24 2013 +0900 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:ankidroid/Anki-Android
```

I saw that you had what looks like pull-requests from other forks in the time between. If Repo2 is meant to be the canonical repo for your project, then you should consider synchronizing with it much more often, to avoid having the history in your own fork diverge too much. "More often" doesn't have to mean "X times per week", it could mean after each pull-request you accept, instead of doing it X pull-requests later.

Comment: Actually, we had about a year (or two?) master when master only contained a README, and all source code was in branches. That's why keeping master up-to-date was not a priority for me. Do you mean the problem would not have happened if I had updated master more often?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul with an unconventional setup like that, I'm not so sure. In general, it's usually a good idea to keep all of your branches up-to-date as often as possible, to reduce conflicts.

Comment: Good analysis of the branches history. More detailed than my answer. +1